# Модуль FS при выполнении функции appendFileSync видит файл только через полный путь

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Есть код

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.appendFileSync("file.txt", "Some text here");
```

При выполнении кода ошибок не выдаёт, но файл по-прежнему остаётся пустым. Пробовал ввести полный путь, все заработало, но нужен краткий путь. Файл file.txt лежит в одной папке с index.js файлом. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не записывается файл?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему на Windows, у меня ваш код работает. На всякий случай, добавьте деталей: операционную систему, версию Node.js. Напишите, как вы обнаруживаете ошибку (сами смотрите файл после работы скрипта или проверяете программно).

Comment: Попробуйте также посмотреть, что выдаёт такой тестовый код: `const fs = require("fs");
console.log(fs.readFileSync("file.txt", "utf8"));
fs.appendFileSync("file.txt", "Some text here");
console.log(fs.readFileSync("file.txt", "utf8"));
`

Comment: ОС: Windows 10
Версия Node.js: 12.18.0

Comment: Кажется, я нашел, в чем проблема. index.js записывает текст не в тот файл. Он записывает все в какой-то другой file.txt. Остаётся узнать, в какой. И как сделать так, чтобы он кратким путём записывал текст в txt файл, который в папке с файлом index.js?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема может быть ещё вот в чём: важно не только, находятся ли файлы `index.js` `file.txt` в одной папке, важно ещё, откуда вы вызываете `index.js`. Если файлы находятся в папке `C:\project\`, а `index.js` вы вызываете из `C:\`, то текущей папкой будет считаться `C:\`, там будет искаться файл `file.txt` — а когда он не будет найден, будет создан заново.

Если хотите записывать в файл в одной со скриптом папке независимо от места вызова скрипта, можно попробовать так:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const path = `${__dirname}\\file.txt`

console.log(fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8"));
fs.appendFileSync(path, "Some text here");
console.log(fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8"));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!